# Reading information in Python in a non-blocking manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I need to read in input from a user in Python, but in a non-blocking manner. I have to check if he pressed a letter, and read it one at a time. There's a great module for doing that: msvcrt. Sadly I can't use it in Ubuntu, so I'm stuck. I saw a similar one called curses for Ubuntu, but I didn't understand how that module works. I need a `getch()` function and a `khbit()` function. The `getch()` on the curses module acts weird and I'm not sure how to operate it. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

NCursos looks daunting at first. But it's more like following a recipe than difficult. The step-by-step [tutorial is here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html#starting-and-ending-a-curses-application). Note that you don't necessarily have to go into the windows part.

[At the end of this page](http://www6.uniovi.es/cscene/CS3/CS3-08.html), there's information on the how to use getch.